# How do you create a 7.1 app in xcode 6 using a universal storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode6, uistoryboard

I'm currently developping an application in xcode 6 for iOS 8.0. Due to changes in the demands of the customer the application now also needs to be able to run on 7.1. I changed the deployment target from 8.0 to 7.1, and the app still builds and compiles. The storyboard is loaded, however the views arn't shown in the application.

Do i need to create new storyboard files to support 7.1, or is there some way to convert the 8.0 one?

Answer (score 1):

Head over to the Interface Builder Document section in the File Inspector panel.

[image]

Then you can change the storyboard settings to suit your client's needs.

Hope this helps,

Will